# Why does flowtype think my variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a flowtype object declaration that looks like this:

```
   type ProjectType = {
     // removed for brevity
     releases?: Array<ReleaseType>
   }
```

There are times when releases is not included in the object, so when I want to use it, I first have a conditional checking for it.  So here, later in my code, I access that array after a conditional like this:

```
   if (selectedProject
      && selectedProject.releases
      && selectedProject.releases.length) {
      majorReleasesSet = new Set(selectedProject.releases.map((release: ReleaseType): string => (
        release.major)));
      projectHasNoReleases = false;
      projectLatestMajorRelease = selectedProject.releases.slice(-1)[0].major;
      projectLatestMinorRelease = selectedProject.releases.slice(-1)[0].minor;
    }
```

But flow does not like this, complaining:

```
Cannot call selectedProject.releases.slice because property slice is missing in undefined [1].

     components/TimeEntries/EntryForm.jsx
     123│         release.major)));
     124│       projectHasNoReleases = false;
     125│       projectLatestMajorRelease = selectedProject.releases.slice(-1)[0].major;
     126│       projectLatestMinorRelease = selectedProject.releases.slice(-1)[0].minor;
     127│     }
     128│
     129│     const projectLatestRelease = `${projectLatestMajorRelease}.${projectLatestMinorRelease}`;
```

What in the world am I missing?  The I tried adding `Array.isArray(selectedProject.releases)` but flow still complained.  Flow lists errors on both lines 125 and 126.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the the fact that you do some potentially effectful things (running a map function, making a set, etc) makes Flow concerned that the `releases` property might have changed on the object. Flow will discard basically any of your refinements after you run a function.

[Here's an example of your code, as-is, throwing an error](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEFkHsGMGtQC4AsCWBnAUAgngBwKagBK+ANvgIZr4AqehAvKAN4aigC2FAVpAE4AuUGgR8UAOwDmAbjacJ-ISLFSANBgC+GLPVAAFPpG75oCOgVBNW7EKD74OkAG74AJqABm-UACN7TlBw5e3IqfDQAfiEAQT4+CmwAHhJQ6nN8AD5NbScKPmEyEwQ3AyMioVLjU3TLFjkuXkFQACIvSGb1dg4FJuafPI7sjFsAZXwEUABXXGFIDkJcsQofcjRPb2R0UHwADwoOXHJhCWhCAElhsFdIcQByCaQKF1AKcWxQaBvinYmbxCQHBhXCZSHkFnlODx+ClKNQ0GMEEIEYlXtgMrJgdBQfZQItQLhDFUEAAJKgAOUgMLCaCEqIxILBuIhBLKpgAMhRiiJwFC+FTqLS3vSsYy8SyiRyuQhwD1+fhBdhZBhPuIRCwQrDwhpatRyKYSoSiqAAD7GlgaWQoDygAAUuqKBtZCAAdBrqaAAGQegp64quSpFV2FanO8hSZAASjqXV5cvh41q4nwAHdQAi7YV9f7DaYg6lws6uLgbTa3QLiMG0vQI0pRBJJJYMray-hC7yIx3ZOxxUVSWgKXHah4KKRqF38TmEJLwtLY5XGD6HdmnXnNWhnWhSChTjaALQARgjAG0AAwAXTbjXHPfZnJnMvE0PnOszfoDuZb6832-we8Pp4vbpHz4WQNCAA)

The easiest way to get around this is to pull the `releases` off of your object into a separate value and perform the null check against that. That way, Flow is sure that it's still not null:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEFkHsGMGtQC4AsCWBnAUAgngBwKagBK+ANvgIZr4AqehAvKAN4aigC2FAVpAE4AuUGgR8UAOwDmAbjacJ-ISLFSANBgC+GLPVAAFPpG75oCOgVBNW7EKD74OkAG74AJqABm-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-jPVkGiAA))

```
// Mock this
type ReleaseType = {
  major: string;
  minor: string,
}

type ProjectType = {
  // removed for brevity
  releases?: Array<ReleaseType>
}

var selectedProject: ProjectType = {
  major: "foo",
  minor: "bar",
}

// Set up some variables for this example since I
// don't have any context on them
declare var majorReleasesSet: Set<any>;
declare var projectHasNoReleases: any;
declare var projectLatestMajorRelease: any;
declare var projectLatestMinorRelease: any;

// The `const {releases} = whateverObject` is the important part here
const {releases} = selectedProject || {};
if (releases && releases.length) {
  majorReleasesSet = new Set(releases.map((release: ReleaseType): string => (release.major)));
  projectHasNoReleases = false;
  projectLatestMajorRelease = releases.slice(-1)[0].major;
  projectLatestMinorRelease = releases.slice(-1)[0].minor;
}
```

Comment: Solid.  This line made all the difference:
`    const { releases } = selectedProject || {};`